# Maximum value of progressbar does not change when the model does

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using [Angular UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) with the following code to display a progressbar:

```
<tr ng-repeat="hero in gamedata.heroes">
    <td>{{hero.name}}</td>
    <td><progressbar max="hero.nextLevel" value="hero.xp">{{hero.xp}}/{{hero.nextLevel}}</progressbar></td>
</tr>
```

This works fine at first, but it breaks the moment I change `hero.nextLevel` in my model. The text inside the progressbar updates fine, but the max attribute doesn't seem to be changed. The progressbar is still filled completely at the value that it was first set to, and then just continues to grow (which is not visible, but the width attribute is still changing if you examine it) until it reaches the new value of `hero.nextLevel`.

As an example, `hero.nextLevel` is set to 10. Once this value is reached, it is set to 20 and XP is set to 0. The progressbar will now be filled again when XP reaches 10, and then continue to grow until it reaches 20, where it will be reset again.

Why is the max attribute not changed when the model changes? And how can I get it to update with the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `progressbar` directive is only watching for change in the `value` and in the `type` properties, [as evidenced by the corresponding code](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/progressbar/progressbar.js). The documentation has a little eye icon after the property name, which is probably here to signify this fact.

Thus, you can't get the `max` value to update with the model, unless you extend by yourself the directive.

Comment: This seems to be it, it looks like it simply wasn't designed the way I assumed. I fixed this now by letting max stay at the default 100 and calculating the fraction myself.